# With SQLAlchemy ORM, how to listen for calls to relationships with "noload", or "raise" set for lazy?

Tags: python, mysql, caching, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My sample tables:

```
class TestEvent(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.id})'


class TestMarket(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.id})'


class TestEventMarket(Model):
    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(TestEvent.id))
    market_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(TestMarket.id))

    event = relationship(TestEvent, lazy='noload',
                         backref=backref('event_markets', lazy='dynamic'))
    market = relationship(TestMarket, lazy='noload',
                          backref=backref('event_markets', lazy='dynamic'))

    PrimaryKeyConstraint(event_id, market_id)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.event_id}:{self.market_id}'
```

Sample init code:

```
event = TestEvent(name='test event1')
market = TestMarket(name='test market1')

em = TestEventMarket(event=event, market=market)

session.add(event)
session.add(market)
session.add(em)
session.commit()
```

Sample query code:

```
event = TestEvent.query.first()
market = TestMarket.query.first()
em = TestEventMarket.query.first()

print(event, market, em)
print(list(map(str, event.event_markets)),
      list(map(str, market.event_markets)),
      em.event, em.market)
```

Which outputs, expectedly:

```
test event1 (1) test market1 (1) 1:1
['1:1'] ['1:1'] None None
```

The reason I want this behaviour, is because, within my application, on startup, I get all "relevant" `TestEvent`s and `TestMarket`s, and cache them.  A new `TestEvent`, or `TestMarket` may be created at some point in the lifecycle, but that's just added to the cache, so all is ok.

These are sample tables, but I've a number of other tables that basically operate as Enum tables, and are used throughout the application.  Because I have these cached, and have a "standard" way to access them, I'd prefer to have the database models use the method.

I've looked through the SQLAlchemy docs, and think it might be able to be done with their `MappedCollection`, or maybe their `HybridAttributes`, but as their completely new concepts to me, I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around them, and figuring out if they're *exactly* what I'm looking for.  Or maybe I should create a custom `InstrumentedAttribute` and have my own `relationship`?  Again, it doesn't "feel" right, and I think there should be a better way to achieve what I'd like.

The *main* thing I want to override or catch, is the "get" portion.  Instead of nothing, or an SQL query, I want it to return something based on my own application logic.

Answer (score 0):

One method that does "work", but I consider ugly as hell, and overkill is the `relationship` declared internally to in `TestEventMarket`, and properties set for calls,

```
class TestEventMarket(Model):
    event_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(TestEvent.id))
    market_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(TestMarket.id))

    _event = relationship(TestEvent, lazy='noload',
                          backref=backref('event_markets', lazy='dynamic'))

    @property
    def event(self):
        if self._event:
            return self._event
        return get_event(self.event_id)

    @event.setter
    def event(self, event: TestEvent):
        if event.id:
            self.event_id = event.id
        self._event = event

    _market = relationship(TestMarket, lazy='noload',
                           backref=backref('event_markets', lazy='dynamic'))

    @property
    def market(self):
        if self._market:
            return self._market
        return get_market(self.market_id)

    @market.setter
    def market(self, market: TestMarket):
        if market.id:
            self.market_id = market.id
        self._market = market

    PrimaryKeyConstraint(event_id, market_id)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.event_id}:{self.market_id}'
```